# Inconsistent snapshot in jest

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jestjs

Has anyone had inconsistent snapshots, as shown in my gist [here](https://gist.github.com/ben-xD/cccc4a1f09f07ccc52fab16a29e12065)? Every time I run `jest`, one of the components has slightly different properties `translateX`and `shadowOpacity`, causing my snapshot test to fail.

To prevent this, I could have render'd shallowly with [ShallowRenderer](https://reactjs.org/docs/shallow-renderer.html), but that was causing a different problem: my useEffect hooks weren't being called. I want to test my `useEffect(() => {}, [])` which run when the component first loads.

Here is my test

```
test('App renders correctly', async () => {
  let app;
  await renderer.act(async () => {
    app = renderer.create(
      <MockedProvider mocks={mockedResponses} addTypename={false}>
        <App />
      </MockedProvider>
    );
  });
  wait();

  expect(app).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
```

Any pointers will be very useful. Thanks

Comment: It would be helpful to see the code that produces inconsistend result. Are these values animeted in some way?